# How much current will I get from the 5V rail of a Teensy 3.2 powered over USB?

Tags: power, current, usb, current-source, teensy

The microcontroller in question is a Teensy 3.2. My understanding is that the most current that you can get from a standard computer USB port is ~180mA; how much of that will current devices attached to the Teensy's Vin (+5V in the case of USB power) receive?

Comment: You must know that there exist different kind of USB ports. Each port with a different maximum Amps.   
USB 2.0 = 0.5 A , USB 3.0/3.1 = 0.9 A, USB BC1.2 = 1.5A, USB type C = 3A and USB-PD (Power delivery) = 20V 5A+ (!!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A USB port can supply at least 100 mA without USB enumeration, and 500 mA or more after successful enumeration. Most PCs (and laptops) don't actually restrict the current in either mode, and you can often draw more than 500 mA, but that is not recommended (or guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112357/how-to-drain-500ma-constantly-from-a-single-usb-port?rq=1).  It seems many computers don't monitor it, and you can draw 500mA without a problem.